# Interpolation of polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have the polynomial $f(x)=x^3$. We can now interpolate it using the values:
$$f(1)=1,f(2)=8,f(3)=27,...$$
Using only one value, we get a constant:
$$f_1(x)=1,\;\{1,1,1,...\}$$
Now using two values, we can get a linear:
$$f_2(x)=7x-6,\;\{1,8,15,...\}$$ 
Proceeding in a similar manner, we get the following:
$$f_3(x)=6x^2-11x+6,\;\{1,8,27,58,...\}$$
$$f_4(x)=x^3,\;\{1,8,27,...\}$$
Obviously $f_n(x)$ for a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n-1$ will be same, now int he above case remaining interpolations at some point give incorrect values and taking these first values we have $\{1,15,58\}$ with sum $74$
We can also interpolate it using Lagrange interpolations:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{}^{n-1}{\mathbb C}_{k}\Delta^kt_k\;,\Delta^{n+1}t_k:=\Delta^{n}t_{k+1}-\Delta^{n}t_{0}\;,\Delta^0t_n:=f(n)$$
Now when we interpolate it using Lagrange interpolation, we get $\Delta^kt_0$'s as $\{1,7,12,6\}$ and thus:
$$f_1(x)=1{}^{x-1}{\mathbb C}_{0}=1\\
f_2(x)=f_1(x)+7{}^{x-1}{\mathbb C}_{1}=1+7x-7=7x-6\\
f_3(x)=f_2(x)+12{}^{x-1}{\mathbb C}_{2}=7x-6+6(x-1)(x-2)=6x^2-11x+6\\
f_4(x)=f_3(x)+6{}^{x-1}{\mathbb C}_{3}=6x^2-11x+6+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=x^3\\
$$
Now I was thinking of making the binomials into a polynomial for which I found that binomial coefficients have a direct relation to polynomials via Stirling Numbers of First Kind. Now I want to ask:

Also Lagrange method would be a little fast as we don't waste our time with matrices.

(Note that I am computing all this with a program (in a programming language) I am writing)

- Is there a direct way of computing the incorrect terms' sum?
- If not, then is this the best method for this approach? I think that maybe polynomial conversion would be necessary and we just find the values of function for each interpolations with subset of Lagrange coefficients via $\mathbb {{}^{n}C_r}$ and sum up incorrect values.
- Is there a direct way of computing Stirling Numbers of first kind?

I need to find a method that should be ideal for large polynomials such as $f(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...11x^{10}$ (at max maybe?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tabulate the correction terms once for all for the monomials $f(x)=1,x,x^2,x^3\cdots x^{10}$. Then the correction terms for an arbitrary polynomial will be the linear combination of the correction polynomials, weighted by the coefficients of the target polynomial.

The interpolating polynomials are
$$1,x\\
1,3x-2,x^2\\
1,7x-6,6x^2-11x+6,x^3\\
1,15x-14,25x^2-60x+36,10x^3-35x^2+5x-24,x^4\\
\cdots$$
and the correction polynomials by difference
$$1,x-1\\
1,3x-3,x^2-3x+2\\
1,7x-7,6x^2-18x+12,x^3-6x^2+11x-6\\
1,15x-15,25x^2-75x+50,10x^3-60x^2+65x-60,x^4-10x^3+35x^2-5x+24\\
\cdots$$

Then the corrections for, say, $x^3-2x$ are
$$1-2(1),7x-7-2(x-1),6x^2-18x+12-2(0),\cdots$$